# Classify the singularity - $f(z)=\dfrac{z}{z^2+\sin^3z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Classify the singularity $z_0=0$ of $f(z)=\dfrac{z}{z^2+\sin^3z}$.

I found that 
$$
\lim_{z \to 0} zf(z) =\lim_{z \to 0} \dfrac{z^2}{z^2+\sin^3z}=1,
$$
so I have a pole of order $1$. Am I right? If yes, then am I ok to tell that the term of order $-1$ is $1$ and the term of order $-2$ is $0$?

Comment: I would think it easier to classify $1/f(z)$. You can use elementary operations on power series.

Comment: @Arthur I don't know this result. Could you show me in using this result?

Comment: It's nothing mysterious. For instance, if $g(z)$ has a pole of order $2$, then $1/g(z)$ has a _zero_ of order $2$, and so on. In this case, we have $$1/f(z)=z+\frac{\sin z}{z}\sin^2z$$ which clearly has a zero of order $1$ at $0$. So the answer you got was correct.

Comment: I agree with you that there is a zero of order $1$ at $0$, but could you clarify why it is "clear"?

Comment: The first term, $z$, has a zero of order $1$. The second term, $\frac{\sin z}{z}\sin^2z$ has a zero of order $2$ (I avoided writing $\frac{\sin^3z}{z}$ in order to emphasise that fact). If you add one function with a zero of order $1$ to another function with a zero of order $2$, the sum has a zero of order one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right: the pole has order $1$. In order to find the residue, you can compute $a$ such that
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\left(\frac{z}{z^2+\sin^3z}-\frac{a}{z}\right)
$$
is finite. The expression becomes
$$
\frac{z^2-az^2-a\sin^3z}{z(z^2+\sin^3z)}
$$
If $a=1$, then the limit is $-1$; therefore the residue is $1$.